# Define position of an object as a function of time such that object travels in fancy ways to a given point within a given duration

Tags: mathematical-modeling, parametrization, spline

For context, I am trying to write animation software and, in doing so, have encountered this problem. I ask that you not be too critical of the setup I have going on because I have no background on the topic.

Let $p(t)$ represent an object's position as a function of time $t\in\mathbb{R}_{\ge0}$. Call $O$ the starting point and $X$ the target point such that $p(0)=O$ and $p(d)=X$, where $d>t$ is the time duration of the movement from $O$ to $X$.

If $O$, $X$, and $d$ are *given*, how should I go about finding $p(t)$?

Of course, there is more to consider here. We could always write an obvious step function
$$
p(t)=\begin{cases}O\quad\text{if}\quad t<d\\X \quad\text{if}\quad t=d\end{cases},
$$
but this is being used for animation; the movement should be somewhat artistically desirable.

If we want the object to move at a constant speed in a straight line from $O$ to $X$, the solution is simple. We have
$$
p(t)=O+\frac{t}{d}(X-O),\tag1
$$
which is really just a parametric equation for a ray with origin $O$ cast towards $X$.

---

I get stuck when I want to get fancier.

- What if I want to have **variable movement speed**? Say, acceleration at the start of the movement and deceleration near the end, similar to that of a car?
- How about **nonlinear paths**? Say I want the object to follow a parabolic (or even sinusoidal, bezier, etc.) curve from $O$ to $X$.

---

I feel as though the answers to the questions above are simple (just some expression involving $O$, $X$, $t$, and $d$), but I cannot visualize solutions past the simple constant speed linear case. What am I thinking wrong?

The only thing I've managed to put together is a more general version of $(1)$:
$$
p(t)=O+\frac{f(t)}{f(d)}(X-O),
$$
where $f$ needs to satisfy $f(0)=0$ and $f(d)\ne0$ so that when $t=0$, we have
$$
p(0)=O+\frac{f(0)}{f(d)}(X-O)=O+0(X-O)=O.
$$
and when $t=d$, we have
$$
p(d)=O+\frac{f(d)}{f(d)}(X-O)=O+X-O=X.
$$
By defining $f$ in different ways, I can finally see some acceleration and deceleration effects. However, I do not know how $f$ exactly relates to the behaviour of the movement which is a big concern when writing software that should be intuitive. Still have no ideas on nonlinear movement either.

Comment: The speed will be proportional to the time derivative $f'(t)$

Comment: You can get rid of the restriction $f(0)=0$ by using $\frac{f(t)-f(0)}{f(d) - f(0)}$ in place of $\frac{f(t)}{f(d)}$, you will need to require $f(d)\ne f(0)$

Comment: You can get motion that is not a straight line by creating a point M that is not colinear with O and X
$$p(t)=O+\frac{f(t)-f(0)}{f(d)-f(0)} \bigg ( X- O + \big (h(t)-h(d) \big ) M \bigg )$$
check out... https://www.desmos.com/calculator/gxlkatvga1

Comment: @WW1 thank you for the suggestions. I would like to know if there exists a name for changing $f(t)$ into $f(t) / f(d)$ and $(f(t) - f(0))/(f(d)-f(0))$. Could I call it normalization?

Answer (score 1):

One way to express things is by using Cartesian plane cordinates. Motion of a point may be modeled as a *path*: a pair of continuous functions
$$
p(t) = \bigl(p_{1}(t), p_{2}(t)\bigr)
$$
satisfying $p(0) = O$ and $p(d) = X$. The image of this path, namely the set of points actually traced out, is the resulting *curve*. The classic toy [*Etch-A-Sketch*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Etch_A_Sketch) implements motion separated into Cartesian components, with one knob controlling $p_{1}$ and one controlling $p_{2}$.

If both components $p_{1}$ and $p_{2}$ are differentiable, the point has a *velocity* $p' = (p_{1}', p_{2}')$ at each time. Note that a differentiable path can trace a curve with corners; a classic example is the *infinitely differentiable* path $p(t) = (\cos^{3} t, \sin^{3}, t)$, which traces the [*astroid*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astroid). If the velocity of $p$ is nowhere zero, however, then a differentiable path traces a curve having a tangent line at each point (aside from technicalities about self-crossing, where we can nitpick what we mean by *tangent line*).

Separately, suppose $p$ is a choice of path from $O$ to $X$, and defined for $0 \leq t \leq d$. "Varying the speed" can be modeled by *reparametrization*. If we want our path to be defined for time $s$ between $a$ and $b$, we can pick a function $\tau$ mapping $[a, b]$ to $[0, d]$ and satisfying $\tau(a) = 0$, $\tau(b) = d$, and considering the path
$$
q(s) = p\bigl(\tau(s)\bigr) = p(t).
$$
If $\tau$ is strictly increasing, $q(s)$ "moves from $O$ toward $X$" as $s$ runs from $a$ to $b$. If $\tau$ "wiggles up and down," $q(s)$ "wiggles back and forth along the chosen curve."

We can "trace a path backwards" by instead picking $\tau$ so that $\tau(b) = 0$ and $\tau(a) = d$. If $\tau$ is strictly decreasing, $q(s)$ "moves from $X$ toward $O$" as $s$ runs from $a$ to $b$. A standard choice is
$$
q(s) = p(d - s),
$$
which is defined for $0 \leq s \leq d$.

<>

For example:

- $p(t) = (t, t^{2})$ traces the part of the parabola $y = x^{2}$ with $0 \leq x \leq 1$ as $t$ runs from $0$ to $1$.
- $q(s) = p(s^{10}) = (s^{10}, s^{20})$ traces the same parabolic arc as $s$ runs from $0$ to $1$, "easing out" of $O = (0, 0)$ and rocketing toward $X = (1, 1)$.
- $q(s) = p\bigl(\sin^{2}(\pi s/2)\bigr) = \bigl(\sin^{2}(\pi s/2), \sin^{4}(\pi s/2)\bigr)$ traces the same parabolic arc as $s$ runs from $0$ to $1$, "easing out" of $O = (0, 0)$ and "easing in" to $X = (1, 1)$. (The point "oscillates back and forth along the parabola" if we let $s$ vary freely.)
- $q(s) = (\sin^{2} s, \sin^{4} s)$ traces the same parabolic arc as $s$ runs from $0$ to $\pi/2$, "easing out" of $O = (0, 0)$ and "easing in" to $X = (1, 1)$.
- $q(s) = p(1 - s) = (1 - s, 1 - 2s + s^{2})$ traces the parabolic arc "backward" from $X$ to $O$ as $s$ runs from $0$ to $1$.

Comment: Thank you for the information. It looks like my introduction of $f(t)$ was really just a reparametrization. That explains the acceleration effects I was seeing. Working parametrically also makes things clear. One more thing: I meant to be more clear about it in my question, but how should we tackle finding a $p(t)$ when *given* $O$, $X$, and $d$? Edited my question to reflect this. Thank you once again!

Comment: The practicalities depend on characteristics you want your curve to have, but if you have a pair of functions that "work qualitatively" you can do "affine rescaling" such as$$O_{1} + (X_{1} - O_{1})\frac{p_{1}(t) - p_{1}(0)}{p_{1}(d) - p_{1}(0)},$$which starts at $O_{1}$ and ends at $X_{1}$, to make the path start and stop where you want.